# How to pass in a lucene query into the .net Neo4J client

Tags: neo4jclient

I'd like to use the .net neo4j client with a a cypher query that starts like this

```
START n=node:node_auto_index('facebookId:("123", "456", "789")')
```

I've noticed that `CypherStartBitWithNodeIndexLookup` requires a key and object value rather than an arbitrary lucene query string.

How should I do this using the .net neo4j client?

Comment: created a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/pull-request/26/added-a-cypher-start-bit-that-allows-an/diff) that might solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CypherStartBitWithNodeIndexLookupWithSingleParameter](https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/src/35383bee74d4d7dcfbc55af5d0eb8ac197738544/Neo4jClient/Cypher/CypherStartBitWithNodeIndexLookupWithSingleParameter.cs?at=default) instead.

Comment: ah ok, now I see what that class is.  Makes sense, please ignore pull request.